# Bash - sed, replace line nr 1 in all matched files

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I have a directory containing many different folders. In these are some php files. I need to change line nr 1 in all files that match a certain string, in all those folders.

All the files I need to change look something this on line nr 1: `<?php some text><?php`

I need to replace all those 1st lines with "`<?php`"

I tried this:

```
grep -rl something /somedir/folder/ | xargs sed -i '' '1s/.*/<?php/
```

But it only replaces *one* of the files in the first folder.

I also tried:

```
grep -rnw something /somedir/folder/ | xargs sed -i '' '1s/.*/<?php/
```

But then I get this error:

```
sed: /somedir/folder//1.php:1:<?php: No such file or directory
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Your solution works fine when you remove the empty string. See my (tested) answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i -e 's/<\?php.*<\?php/<?php/' `find ./ -type f`
```

To explain:

```
sed -i
```

Run, with sed editing in-place

```
-e 's/
```

a replacement command, replacing

```
<\?php.*<\?php
```

two consecutive php opening statements (escaping the question marks, because this is a regex)

```
/
```

with

```
<?php
```

one php opening statement

```
/'
```

once per line.

```
`find ./ -type f`
```

for everything in this folder that's a file.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. However, when I run that, all that happens is  that I get an ">", where my marker gets placed, like it's awaiting input. I'm running my Terminal on my Mac, I don't know if that is related somehow.

Comment: My bad - I was fighting with the SO syntax to get the command there un-escaped and I accidentally left a backslash there. Removed it. Please try again.

Comment: This searches through the hole file. A very inefficient way to replace the first line.

Comment: @ceving that's so that anybody using this as a template for a similar change won't wonder why only the first line is changed. Also, you're spending much more time searching for files than `sed` actually takes to do this in nearly all cases... Note also I didn't limit the `find` to just PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

```
find ./ -iname "*.php" -exec sed '1 s/^<?php some text><?php$/<?php/' -i {} \;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I tried this. It does find all the files, but it does not replace line nr 1. Seems to leave the files just the way they where before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the intention of the empty string was, when executing sed. Without it it works totally fine for me:

```
grep -rl something /somedir/folder/ | xargs sed -i '1s/.*/<\?php/'
```

Comment: When I run it without the empty string, I get "invalid command code V". Im using the terminal on my Mac, I don't know if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Well, I tested it on Linux since you tagged your question with Linux. I don't know how or if the Mac version differs, but an empty string doesn't make sense at all, since the `''` isn't really a string, the single quotes are for escaping.

Comment: Maybe it helps, when you post what you tried **exactly**, since there's no `V` in the command you posted. Therefore with this error message we can only guess, what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, this is exactly what I tried:
`grep -rl fepm3hopmA /Users/Vega/Desktop/test-files/ | xargs sed -i '1s/.*/<\?php/' `

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -rl something /somedir/folder/ | xargs sed -i '' '1s/.*/<\?php/'
```

This sort of works. But it only changes the file it finds first. And not all files. So basically with this I would have to run it 100 times if I have 100 files =)

Any idea how I can get around that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Now, since I am on OSX, apparently sed does not work exactly the same way as on Linux. Which I did not know. But this is how it can be done:

```
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed -i '' -e '1s/.*/<?php/' {} \;
```

I don't understand exactly why it needs to be like this, but it works.